# Angular multiple sort, order by

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-orderby

probably a very nooby question and I'm missing obvious but I'm using a function to sort  my results.
Each result has a price and a weighting (priority basically)

I want the results ordered by price but there are results with the same price, they need to be ordered by the weight. I can also reverse the ordering, so low-high/high-low.

Here is a plunker with some noddy data:

http://plnkr.co/edit/VH2WvyJMsLSTpWJawT2f?p=preview

In my app (I have hundreds of results), I used this

```
$scope.orderByFunction = function (result) {
    if ($scope.orderBy == 'price-low-high') {
        return result.totalPrice.amount + result.boost;
    }
    if ($scope.orderBy == 'price-high-low') {
        return -result.totalPrice.amount + result.boost;
    }
    else return result.totalPrice.amount + result.boost;
};
```

Whilst I thought it was initially successful, it got some wrong as it show higher priced results above lower priced ones. Appreciate it's hard for me to show that so I figured I'd ask the noddy question first :)

Comment: i tried it a bit...not seeing irregular sort

Comment: See now. I've added more results and used the above ordering code
http://plnkr.co/edit/VH2WvyJMsLSTpWJawT2f?p=preview

Price 150 shows above price 100. Guessing it's some really silly error on my part.

Comment: suggest you scale down repeat elemnt sizes `H1`??  and give people steps to replicate...I jsut don't see it

Comment: ok. See this:
http://embed.plnkr.co/VH2WvyJMsLSTpWJawT2f/

try changing the sort in the drop down. basically it's all wrong. It should be in price order and then if the same price, ordered by the weighting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered over at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/XAJ2hyeRSTU

This is the html http://plnkr.co/edit/VH2WvyJMsLSTpWJawT2f?p=preview
orderBy: [orderByPrice, orderByPriority]

and the JS

```
$scope.orderByPrice = function (result) {
    if ($scope.orderBy == 'price-low-high') {
        return result.amount;
    }
    if ($scope.orderBy == 'price-high-low') {
        return -result.amount;
    }
    else return result.totalPrice.amount;
};
$scope.orderByPriority = function (result) {
        return result.priority;
};
```